# Python add key to list of dictionary if key doesn't exist

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

I want to add the key 'Name' to list of dictionaries in whichever dictionary 'Name' doesn't exist.

For example,

```
[dict(item, **{'Name': 'apple'}) for item in d_list]
```

will update value of key 'Name' even if key already exists and

```
[dict(item, **{'Name': 'apple'}) for item in d_list if 'Name' not in item]
```

returns empty list

Comment: you are looking for the `.setdefault` method on a dictionary

Comment: What's the content of `d_list` ?

Comment: d_list contains list of dictionaries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Abdul Aziz comment, I could do it in 1 line using

```
[item.setdefault("Name", 'apple') for item in d_list]
```

Comment: This solution has two problems: --- 1 --- It misuses list comprehension to perform a side-effect on the arguments. List comprehension should only be used to generate a new list, not modify the input data. --- 2 --- You throw away the list generated by the list comprehension. ------ Please instead of misusing list comprehension use a simple for loop. The code would be much more readable and predictable. ------ `for item in d_list: item.setdefault("Name", 'apple')`

Answer (score 3):

You need to handle the two different cases. In case the list is empty, and if it's not.

It's not possible to handle both use-cases in a single list comprehension statement since when the list is **empty**, it will always return *zero-value (empty list)*. It is like doing `for i in my_list`. If the list is empty, the code inside the for block won't be executed.

I would tackle it with a single loop. I find it more readable.

```
>>> default = {"Name": "apple"} 
>>> miss_map = {"Data": "text"}
>>> exist_map = {"Name": "pie"}
>>>
>>> d = [miss_map, exist_map]
>>>
>>> list_dict = [miss_map, exist_map]
>>> for d in list_dict:
...     if "Name" not in d.keys():
...             d.update(default)
...
>>> list_dict
[{'Data': 'text', 'Name': 'apple'}, {'Name': 'pie'}]
>>>
```

You can then move it to it's own function and pass it the list of dicts.

Answer (score 0):

In one line of code:

```
d_list = [{**d, "Name": "apple"} for d in d_list if "Name" not in d] + [d for d in d_list if "Name" in d]
```